# $G$ is a finite group s.t. $(ab)^p=a^pb^p$; $P$ is its $p$-Sylow subgroup. Then there exists $N \unlhd G$ such that $N \cap P = (e)$ and $NP=G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This is problem 2.12.15  in Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*, second edition. The full problem is

> Let $G$ be a finite group in which $(ab)^p=a^pb^p$ for every $a,b \in G$, where $p$ is a prime dividing $o(G)$. Prove
>
> (a) The $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is normal in $G$.
>
> $^*$(b) If $P$ is the $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, then there exists a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ with $P \cap N = (e)$ and $PN=G$.
>
> (c) $G$ has a nontrivial center.

I have done part (a) but am stuck at part (b). I have tried different approaches, but they all seem ineffective. I should also say that, at this point in the book, Herstein hasn't even formally introduced direct products, only the Sylow theorems. How am I supposed to solve this?

The next problem, problem 16, basically asks to prove a result called *Burnside's p-complement theorem* or possibly another called the *Schur-Zassenhaus theorem* (according to other threads on this website), but that's a double-starred problem, so I was thinking that there must be a simpler solution to this one-star problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The map $\phi:a\mapsto a^p$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $G$. If $|P|=p^r$, then
$\phi^s$ has kernel $P$ wherever $s\ge r$. Let $|G|=p^rm$. Choose $s\ge r$
with $p^s\equiv 1\pmod m$. Let $N$ be the image of $\phi^s$. It has order $m$,
by the first isomorphism theorem.
Its elements all satisfy $a^m=e$. But if $a^m=e$ then $\phi^s(a)=a$, so $N=\{a\in G:a^m=e\}$, and so is a characteristic subgroup
of $G$. But obviously, $P\cap N$ is trivial, and so $PN$ must have order
$p^rm=|G|$.

Comment: Does this also ensure the normalcy of $N$?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 Yes. This shows that $N$ is the *only* subgroup of order $m$ in $G$, and therefore it is fixed by any automorphism (so it's said to be *characteristic*), because the isomorphic image of a subgroup must have the same cardinality; and in particular it is fixed by inner automorphisms, i.e. conjugation. So it's normal.

Comment: Very clever, Lord Shark. In fact, I understand the proof but I don't understand how I could have arrived at it. First of all, how did you know that normality was going to be proved through uniqueness of the subgroup, rather than the more general case $x^{-1}Nx \subset N$? And once you understood that, how did you know that the inverse image of each $a$ of order $m$ had to be $a$ itself? You just guessed that, because it was the simplest case, and it turned out to work?

Comment: @TheFootprint Your condition states that $a\mapsto a^p$ is an endomorphism of $G$. So one way to use it is to investigate this homomorphism and see what it tells you....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes, I had used that fact in part (a). But here you have $\phi(G)$ and you want to prove that it's normal. I was interested in the "logic steps" that lead to your solution.  It's very hard for a newbie to notice that there is an $s$ such that $\phi^s(a)=a$, when $a^m=e$ before knowing that you will need this fact! The way I would arrive at your solution is to first guess that normality can be proved by uniqueness of the subgroup. Then I have to find $x$ such that $\phi^s(x)=x^{p^s}=a$ for each $a$ of order $m$. To do that I have to guess the form of $x$. It isn't trivial

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Maybe I just lack the practice to notice these patterns. But I was wondering if my "steps" were correct anyway, or if there is a more intuitive thought process

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Actually, a simpler proof would be: let $\phi : x \mapsto x^p$. If $y \in \phi^r(G)$, then $y=g^{p^r}$ for some $g$, so $x^{-1}yx=x^{-1}g^{p^r}x=(x^{-1}gx)^{p^r} \in \phi^r(G)$. Therefore $\phi^r(G)$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ be set of elements of $G$ whose order is not divisible by $p$. Let $a,b\in N$ and set $n=lcm(|a|,|b|)$. Since $gcd(p,n)=1$, there exists positive $k$ such that $p^k\equiv 1 \ mod \ n$ (one may take $k=\varphi(n$)).

Now, $$(ab)^{p^k}=a^{p^k}b^{p^{k}}=ab.$$

This shows that $ab\in \langle (ab)^p \rangle$, and so  $|ab|=|(ab)^p|$. Thus, the order of $ab$ is not divisible by $p$. It follows that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$. Since $a$ and $g^{-1}ag$ are of same order, $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Clearly, $N\cap P=1$ and $G/N$ is a $p$-group. Thus, $G=NP$ as desired.

Comment: Nice. I find it easier to prove that $ab \in N$ by multiplying by $(ab)^{-1}$ to get $(ab)^{p^k-1}=e$. So $o(ab) \mid p^k-1 \implies p \not \mid o(ab)$. Correct? Also, I would perhaps highlight the fact that $G/N$ is a *Sylow* $p$-group?

Comment: Yes, your argument about the order of $ab$ is correct and shorter.  Now when a group is a $p$-group, I think there is no need to call it as a Sylow subgroup.